# Books to self-study Immanuel Kant

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, reference-request, kant

I am impressed by Kant's moral or nominative laws- hypothetical imperative and categorical imperative as well as the three versions of the categorical imperative.

I want to grasp whatever Kant wrote. Could someone please refer some **illustrative books** which explain **Kant's** work in an easy to understand manner?

Comment: It seems to me English is not your native language. Are you looking for books in English, or in another language?

Comment: in english but explanation should be easy to follow.

Comment: do you want the books to merely be commentaries on the text or do you want them to be more substantive interpretations? Also are you coming at this from the perspective of law (as in the academic discipline of law)? This seems implied in your first sentence. Also, where are you getting the number three about versions? All of this would help in knowing what sort of resources you want.

Comment: 1. i want books such that they are complete in letting me understand kant. 2. This is not due to any academic reasons, but a mere urge to understand  kant.

Comment: A classics is "H.J.Paton: The Categorial Imperative. A Study in Kant's Moral Philosophy (1947)". It starts with the basics and advances to rather subtle aspects of its topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a book that explains Kant entirely? Then you should read Kant's work itself. But then it won't be easy to understand. If you want to have something easy to understand, you'll have to accept it won't be complete. You have to make a compromise somewhere.

Anyway...

You may find this video and the others in the same series interesting: http://youtu.be/kLwiBg4sCaE - of course they oversimplify things.

For more, Roger Scruton wrote [a 135-pages introduction to Kant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192801996). Also this is not enough to explain everything, but what Scruton does very neatly, besides giving a basic introduction, is showing the modern relevance of Kant's work.

If you're going to read a primary text, I would advise to read an opponent alongside. It always helps to get a better idea of the context and the issues they're dealing with. When I read Kant's Critique of Practical Reason, I read Nietzsche's Also Sprach Zarathustra alongside.

Comment: i appreciate your answer. is there a book that extensively makes use of examples and counter examples to explain what kant wants to say ? i dont mean that book should cover whole of kant's work.

Comment: @ketan the book I mentioned uses some examples, not more than other books though. I don't know of any book that does - but on this site we have some questions about examples of Kantian theory, and you can also ask yourself of course.